# Change Ember build directory (dist folder) without command line flags

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to make my Ember project build to a directory outside of the project and for future builds I don't want to use command line flags each time. 
`ember build --output-path=/not-dist` will work for me but I want Ember to add the flag automatically.

```
    outputPaths: {
      app: {
        html: '../presentation/index.cfm',
        css: {
          'app': '../presentation/assets/ember-presentation-viewer.css'
        },
        js: '../presentation/assets/ember-presentation-viewer.js'
      },
      vendor: {
        css: '../presentation/assets/vendor.css',
        js: '../presentation/assets/vendor.js'
      }
    }
```

I have tried this as per the [ember-cli documentation](https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation#configuring-output-paths) but `ember-presentation-viewer.css` was insisting on getting built in the `dist` directory with all the additional paths put there.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you also want this for development builds during `ember serve`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your `.ember-cli.js` file to specify flags that should always be included in your command line builds (in lower camel case), as per [this page](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/configuring-ember/configuring-ember-cli/) in the Ember docs. To change the output directory you'll want to add the following line: `"outputPath": "../../example-folder/presentation"`.

So your final `.ember-cli.js` should look like this:

```
{
  /*
    Ember CLI sends analytics information by default. The data is completely
    anonymous, but there are times when you might want to disable this behavior.

    Setting `disableAnalytics` to true will prevent any data from being sent.
  */
  "disableAnalytics": false,
  "outputPath": "../../example-folder/presentation"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to `package.json`. Change `scripts/build` command:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ember build --output-path=/not-dist"
},
```

From now on, run:

`npm run build`